# NodeJS - Typescript - Intellisense

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, intellisense

In VS2013, intelliSense in a NodeJS App in a *.js file works like a charm. I was wondering if there is also intelliSense supported in a TypeScript file for several NodeJS-Modules? How can I enable intelliSense for NodeJS in a TypeScript file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DefinitelyTyped is the place to look for typescript definition files:
https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/node

You can use your favorite package manager to get it and all of the DefinitelyTyped deffinitions are available in NuGet.

There are a quite a few specific NPM modules on there too, but some you will have to define yourself.

In VS2013 when you add a deffinition file (*.d.ts) then it will be available from the IntelliSense.